# Connect to a non-Meteor server with websockets?

Tags: websocket, meteor

I'm having trouble using websockets in Meteor and there seem to be mixed messages about whether or not this is even possible. Can anyone shed some light on this issue for me? Ultimately, I'm trying to connect to a server that is not running Meteor. Is this where DDP comes in?

My most recent test was with Sock.js using the following sample code:

```
<script src="http://cdn.sockjs.org/sockjs-0.3.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    var sock = new SockJS('ws://echo.websocket.org/');

    sock.onopen = function() {
        console.log('open');
    alert(sock.readyState);
    };

    sock.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log('message', e.data);
    alert(sock.readyState);
    };

    sock.onclose = function() {
        console.log('close');
    alert(sock.readyState);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Whether this example works or not does not depend on the presence of Meteor, but rather the server ability to handle websockets.

Comment: Can you tell more about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @TomaszLenarcik, I am trying to (but cannot) achieve similar thing... Opening a WebSocket client in meteor js server.
It is possible in meteor js client but in server error is displayed: WebSocket is undefined.
I tried adding sockjs etc packages like joncursi:socket-io-client)